# convert image to caricatures android

Tags: android, image

I am looking for a way to convert an image into a funny caricature for my android app. Is there a library to do so?I came across many libraries that provide filters. I in particular am looking for caricatures. That is converting someone's profile picture into a funny cartoon etc.

Comment: But when? Dinamically? In execution time? That will be complicated... If you only want to use those images in your app you can use any online converter... http://www.cartoonize.net/ and then use them in your app...

Comment: At run time. User should be given a list of options to choose from. For example a list of different cartoon characters that he can turn himself into. After his selection, the transformation should be applied and returned to the user in image format.

Comment: Uuuufff. I dont know any library for that. Maybe someone can help you. Good luck @Mahak Garg...

Comment: @EliasMP have you seen any example how to do this? I mean to use online converter for images